# Where and How is a UIWebview's sessionStorage cached/stored

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, sessionstorage

Where and How (from a security point of view) is a UIWebview's sessionStorage cached/stored?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same as safari mobiles. If you save your pwd n username for you uiwebview it'll correlate to safari mobile n vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

NSHTTPCookie's singleton instance stores the Cookie information on App basis.